# counting number of appearances of the given value

Tags: r

I have a string and need to count number of appearances of a given value which must appear consequent. I tried to take help from stringr package but it counts every time it finds that value/pattern. For example, say we have to count appearance of "213" in string "2132132132137889213", then the output i need is 4 however, i am  getting 5 after using stringr_count function. Please help.

Comment: Suppose your string is "2132132132137889213213", what would be the count?

Comment: Hm, maybe adding the `regex` tag would help in finding a general solution?

Comment: Or if you have `"213353453213213"`, would you want only the first appearance or the last two (because they are consequent)?

Comment: yes, then the output must be 2 of "213" for the string you mentioned. @DavidArenburg

Comment: @akrun then also answer i want is 4. If the string is "2132132139876213213213213213" then answer must be 5. Maximum repetitions i need.

Comment: So you want only the first sequence that is over 1?

Comment: @akrun count = 5. Maximum of 4,5,2 is 5.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure of my "regex" skills but, hopefully, you could make something out of this:

```
max_rep_pat = function(pat, text)
{
   res = gregexpr(paste0("(", pat, ")+"), text)
   sapply(res, function(x) max(attr(x, "match.length")) / nchar(pat))
}
max_rep_pat("213", c("2132132132137889213", 
                     "21321321321378892132132132132132213213"))
#[1] 4 5
```

`gregexpr` returns the position a pattern occured and the number of characters of the found pattern. Wrapping the pattern in "(pattern)+" means 'find the repetitive pattern'. Compare the following two:

```
gregexpr("213", "2132132132137889213") 
[[1]]
[1]  1  4  7 10 17
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 3 3 3 3 3
#attr(,"useBytes")
#[1] TRUE

gregexpr("(213)+", "2132132132137889213") 
[[1]]
[1]  1 17
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 12  3
#attr(,"useBytes")
#[1] TRUE
```

In the first case, it found the position of each "213" and the length of each match is just the `nchar` of pattern. In the second case, it found every repetitive pattern of "213" and we see that repetitions of "213" occured two times; first time with 12 / 3 = 4 repetitions and the second with 3 / 3 = 1 repetition. Using `max(attr(x, "match.length")) / nchar(pattern)` we get that 4.

Comment: Great answer. @alexis_laz Can you provide explanation as well?

Comment: if I wish to find out an ARITHMETIC PROGRESSION SERIES in a string, how can I do it? Eg: `1 2 3 4 7 9 11 13` , here I can see that, `(1,2,3,4)` form a continuous series, and `(7,9,11,13)` also, forms one, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be:

```
 fun1 <- function(pat, text) {
max_rep_pat1 <- function(pat, text) {
    text1 <- gsub(pat, paste(" ", pat, " "), text)
    rl <- rle(scan(text = text1, what = "", quiet = T) == pat)
    max(rl$lengths[rl$values])
 }
setNames(mapply(max_rep_pat1, pat, text), NULL)

}

str1 <- c("2132132132137889213", "21321321321378892132132132132132213213")
str2 <- "213421342134213477"
fun1("2134", str2)
#[1] 4
fun1("213", str1)
#[1] 4 5
```

Comment: Thank you! @akrun Can you explain the line:-max(table(cumsum(c(T,diff(unlist(t2))>3)))) ?

Comment: It works only for 3 length string, if i give "213421342134213477" and string to find is "2134", it wont work then. Length of the string can be anything.

Comment: @user3845968.  Sorry, I didn't tested it earlier.  I will delete this.

Comment: if I wish to find out an ARITHMETIC PROGRESSION SERIES in a string, how can I do it? Eg: 1 2 3 4 7 9 11 13 , here I can see that, (1,2,3,4) form a continuous series, and (7,9,11,13) also, forms one, how can I do this?  @akrun

Comment: @user3845968.  Not sure if you posted this question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851973/arithmetic-progression-series-in-r> It already have two answers.

Comment: yes I saw that, but the thing is, one of the answers is completely vague about tree structures and the other one, just calculates the AP series with difference as `1`, i.e. `(1,2,3,4,5,6..)`. But it doesn't find series like, `(2,4,6,8)` or `(3,6,9,12..)`. That is the problem.