# Arithmetic Progression series in R

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I am new to this forum. I guess something like this has been asked before but, I am not really sure if that is what I want.

I have a sequence like this,

```
1 2 3 4 5 8 9 10 12 14 15 17 18 19
```

So, what I wish to do is this, get all the numbers which form a series,i.e.the numbers that belonging to that set should all have a constant difference with the previous element, and also the minimum number of elements should be 3 in that set.

i.e., I can see that `(1,2,3,4,5)` forms one such series in which numbers appear after an interval of 1 and the total size of this set is 5 which satisfies the minimum threshold criteria. 
`(1,3,5)` forms one such a pattern in which the numbers appear after an interval of 2.

`(8,10,12,14)` forms another such pattern with an interval of 2. So, as you can see, the interval of repetition can be anything.

Also, for a particular set, I want its maximal one. I dont want, `(8,10,12)` (although it satisfies the minimum threshold of 3 and constant difference ) as the output and only of the maximal length I want, i.e. `(8,10,12,14)`.

Similarly, for, `(1,2,3,4,5)` , I dont want `(1,2,3)` or `(2,3,4,5)` as the output, only the MAXIMAL LENGTH ONE I WANT, i.e. `(1,2,3,4,5)`.

How can I do this in R?

Edit: That is, I want any set which forms a basic AP series with any difference, however the total value should be greater than 3 in that series and it should be maximal.

Edit2: I have tried using `rle` and `acf` in R but that doesnt entirely solves my problem.

Edit3: When I did `acf`, it basically gave me the maximum peak difference that I could have used. However, I want all the differences possible. Also, `rle` is just way different. It gave me the longest continuous sequence of similar numbers. Which is not there in my case.

Comment: That's a lot of questions. You should start with `rle`.

Comment: This seems pretty similar to one of the [featured questions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801741/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-single-string-of-characters-in-r)

Comment: @Roman, I tried that, but it doesnt give me what I want since, it gives me continuous length encoding. I did try that before posting. :)

Comment: @nrussell, yes as I said, something like this has been asked before, and I had a look at that before posting it. But, mine is quite different, although they do hold some similarity. :)

Comment: @bjohn It would be a good idea to include reproducible code from your best attempt(s) at solving this problem, and a description of where it falls short.

Comment: In addition to `rle`, looking at `diff` and `findInterval` could be useful.

Comment: @nrussell, I have really tried very hard to do it on my own. But I wasnt able to do it. I will be glad if you can help me with it. :)

Comment: @RichardScriven, I did `diff` and it calculated the difference between adjacent values. For example, for the above string I got, `1 1 1 1 3 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 1`. How should I go ahead further? Thanks. :)

Comment: Well you're looking for the longest such sequence of constant differences right?  You used diff to get the differences.  Now what other function has been mention that can give you the length of these sections that are constant?  `rle`.

Comment: @Dason, Thanks for the help but, For example: `4 5 7 8 10 11` In this string, if you see, the AP's formed that will satisfy the constraints are, `(4,7,10)` and `(5,8,11)` and on computing the difference, it will be, `1 2 1 2 1` , here, as you can see that the same difference doesnt turn out to be constant in length so `rle` wont work completely.

Comment: Oh I wasn't paying enough attention.  If the elements don't need to be sequential then it sounds like you might just need to brute force it.

Comment: @Dason, that will do. But, how should I go about it? A algorithm/code might be of great help here. Thanks. :)

Comment: I think it's time we all backed up and asked the real question: *What is the problem you are trying to solve?*  What are these integer sequences related to, and why do repeated patterns matter? There's probably a much better approach to the root problem.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, believe me on this. I have a sequence like this only in which I wish to find maximal length AP series of all kinds. Basically, they will act as patterns with a constant difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for sequences of **consecutive** numbers, then `cgwtools::seqle` will find them for you in the same way `rle` finds a sequence of repeated values.

In the general case of basically any subset of your data which form such a sequence, such as the  `8,10,12,14` case you cite, your criteria are so general as to be very difficult to satisfy.  You'd have to start at each element of your series and do a forward-looking search for  `x[j] +1,  x[j]+2, x[j]+3 ...` ad infinitum.   This suggests using some tree-based algorithms.

Comment: I understood your point. But, if I have a fixed length string, let's say of 15 value at maximum, then also, will it require using a tree algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potential solution - albeit a very ugly, sloppy one:

```
##
arithSeq <- function(x=nSeq, minSize=4){
  ##
  dx <- diff(x,lag=1)
  Runs <- rle(diff(x))
  ##
  rLens <- Runs[[1]]
  rVals <- Runs[[2]]
  pStart <- c(
    rep(1,rLens[1]),
    rep(cumsum(1+rLens[-length(rLens)]),times=rLens[-1])
  )
  pEnd <- pStart + c(
    rep(rLens[1]-1, rLens[1]),
    rep(rLens[-1],times=rLens[-1])
  )
  pGrp <- rep(1:length(rLens),times=rLens)
  pLen <- rep(rLens, times=rLens)
  dAll <- data.frame(
    pStart=pStart,
    pEnd=pEnd,
    pGrp=pGrp,
    pLen=pLen,
    runVal=rep(rVals,rLens)
  )
  ##
  dSub <- subset(dAll, pLen >= minSize - 1)
  ##
  uVals <- unique(dSub$runVal)
  ##
  maxSub <- subset(dSub, runVal==uVals[1])
  maxLen <- max(maxSub$pLen)
  maxSub <- subset(maxSub, pLen==maxLen)
  ##
  if(length(uVals) > 1){
    for(i in 2:length(uVals)){
      iSub <- subset(dSub, runVal==uVals[i])
      iMaxLen <- max(iSub$pLen)
      iSub <- subset(iSub, pLen==iMaxLen)
      maxSub <- rbind(
        maxSub,
        iSub)
      maxSub
    }
    ##
  }
  ##
  deDup <- maxSub[!duplicated(maxSub),]
  seqStarts <- as.numeric(rownames(deDup))
  outList <- list(NULL); length(outList) <- nrow(deDup)
  for(i in 1:nrow(deDup)){
    outList[[i]] <- list(
      Sequence = x[seqStarts[i]:(seqStarts[i]+deDup[i,"pLen"])],
      Length=deDup[i,"pLen"]+1,
      StartPosition=seqStarts[i],
      EndPosition=seqStarts[i]+deDup[i,"pLen"])
    outList
  }
  ##
  return(outList)
  ##
}
##
```

So there are things that can definitely be improved in this function - for instance I made a mistake somewhere in the calculation of `pStart` and `pEnd`, the start and end indices of a given arithmetic sequence, but it just so happened that the true start positions of such sequences are given as the rownumbers of one of the intermediate data.frames, so that was a hacky sort of solution. Anyways, it accepts a numeric vector `x` and a minimum length parameter, `minSize`. It will return a list containing information about sequences meeting the criteria you outlined above.

```
set.seed(1234)
lSeq <- sample(1:25,100000,replace=TRUE)
nSeq <- c(1:10,12,33,13:17,16:26)
##
> arithSeq(nSeq)
[[1]]
[[1]]$Sequence
 [1] 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26

[[1]]$Length
[1] 11

[[1]]$StartPosition
[1] 18

[[1]]$EndPosition
[1] 28
##
> arithSeq(x=lSeq,minSize=5)
[[1]]
[[1]]$Sequence
[1] 13 16 19 22 25

[[1]]$Length
[1] 5

[[1]]$StartPosition
[1] 12760

[[1]]$EndPosition
[1] 12764


[[2]]
[[2]]$Sequence
[1] 11 13 15 17 19

[[2]]$Length
[1] 5

[[2]]$StartPosition
[1] 37988

[[2]]$EndPosition
[1] 37992
```

Like I said, its sloppy and inelegant, but it should get you started.

Comment: I am cannot thank you enough for this. Really. It works good. However, I have just one doubt. The `nSeq` in the example above yields after sorting ` 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 12 33 13 14 15 16 17 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26` . Now, on finding out sequences in this, why is it that it finds out only those AP's which have a constant difference equal to `1`. Can the code be modified to include to output the series such as `2,4,6,8,10,12,14....` ? And, also, with difference equal to 3?

Comment: It should take that into account - it is looking for any type of arithmetically increasing sequence, not just increments of 1. Note the example I gave using `lSeq` as `x` and `minSize=5`: The first result in the list is `13 16 19 22 25` (differences of 3); and the second in the list is `11 13 15 17 19` (differences of 2).

Comment: After sorting the `nSeq`, I did this, `arithSeq(nSeq,minSize=3)` and it returns two sequences. One is from `1 2 3...10` and the other is `17 18 19 .. 26`. I dont know why is this happening?

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying - that happened because they are the same length (10). If there are two or more arithmetic sequences with the same increment, it takes the longest one; but if there are multiple sequences with the same increment and length, it just returns all with that (max) length. The alternative would be just to pick one of them arbitrarily, which could easily be implemented.

Comment: but the sequence, `2 4 6 8 10 ... ` have increments of `2` and sequence `3 6 9 12 .... ` have increments of `3`. Why it doesn't return these series?

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you were looking for - I thought you were trying to get arithmetic sequences based on consecutive values in the input vector x. Determining arithmetic sequences - without the restriction that values must occur consecutively - would require much more effort than I have time to invest at the moment, but you should be able to modify the above code to get that. Note that a sequence of say, 1,2,3,...,14,15, which is incremented by 1, implies many nonconsecutive sequences like 2,4,...,14, 1,3,...,15, 1,5,9,13, etc... exist.

Comment: is the `diff(x,lag=2)` calculating the sequences with difference = `1`?

Comment: That would calculate x[j] - x[j-2]. So I suppose if you iterate over values of `lag = 1,2,3,...,15` with the above function, you can get non consecutive arithmetic progressions.

Comment: I tried to set `diff(x,lag=2)` and `diff(x,lag=3)` in the first line of the function. The function gave the same output as it did originally with `diff(x,lag=1)`. I guess it won't work that way.